# ¿Cómo cargar 3 tabs con fragments distintos, si estos tienen recyclerviews diferentes?

Tags: android-studio, recyclerview, fragment

Tengo una tab que debe mostrarme 3 fragments diferentes en un ViewPager... Soy novato, pero encontré un ejemplo casi ajustado a lo que requiero; el único detalle es que me carga el mismo fragment en las 3 tabs; y cuando intento cargar un fragment distinto en alguna de las secciones de la tab, entonces se detiene la app...

Acá dejo mi MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter =
                new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        // Iterate over all tabs and set the custom view
        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
            tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "SONANDO", "PLAYLIST", "CANCIONES" };
        Context context;

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
            super(fm);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tabTitles.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:

                    return new BlankFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new PlaylistFragment();
                case 2:
                    return new BlankFragment();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            // Generate title based on item position
            return tabTitles[position];
        }

        public View getTabView(int position) {
            View tab = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            tv.setText(tabTitles[position]);
            return tab;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Endy, en el caso de Android es importante el uso del LogCat, revisa que mensaje se muestra. Te invito a realizar el [tour], saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Si tus `Fragments` tienen `RecyclerViews`, en este caso no es importante.

Puedo notar un detalle importante que definitivamente causa un error, y es agregar un `Toolbar` cuando ya se tiene uno dentro del layout, te sugiero eliminar ambas lineas:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); //obtiene referencia de Toolbar en layout.
setSupportActionBar(toolbar); //Agrega Toolbar.
```

Como no realizas ninguna modificación en el `Toolbar` puedes prescindir de ambas lineas.